# Can't get textView. in activity layout xml set id textView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio

```
package com.example.myapplication2
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
fun countMe(view: View){
    val countString = textView.text.toString()
    var count: Int = Integer.parseInt(countString)
    count++
}
```

I Can't get textView. in activity layout xml set id textView. "I'm having trouble retrieving the value from a text field within a Kotlin method in Android Studio."

Comment: Please show us the content of activity_main. Also, where do you call countMe() and where textview is referenced? You're actual code won't do anything but display the content of activity_main

Comment: textView is the View ID of the text field in the layout of the activity. In this context, textView is the identifier for the text field in the activity_main.xml file, which is used to lay out the user interface.

Comment: Ok, so how are you expecting to get that view? There's no way android will just guess 'textview' is the view you want to use. How do you plan on telling android that ''hey buddy, go inside my layout file and use the view which has an id of 'textView' .''.

Comment: I'm asking all these question to help you understand how this works

Comment: actually i don't know how to get that view

Comment: val countString = textView.text.toString()  doesn't work

Comment: Ok I see. As an advice, I'll recommand you learn basic android development on various site online or on youtube courses. What you're trying to do is: ```val textView = findViewById("textView)``` then ```val countString  = textView.text.toString()```

Comment: You'll actually have to call your countMe() method within the onCreate() method of your activity

Comment: no. I guess I couldn't explain to you what the problem is

Comment: how can i show you  content of activity_main. its to long

Comment: You could just put the relevant part, such as the textView you're trying to use and some code that shows how you're doing so. In your question there is no where you're being calling countMe() for example

Comment: i just need to get the values of the textview textbox. but for some reason it is not possible to do it in the way indicated in the code

Comment: There's no "some reason", the reason is you're not doing things properly. Things won't just work magically. Learn basic android programming.

Answer (score 0):

Where are the "textView" variable coming from?

It seems like it's missing binding the view. The easiest way is:

```
val textView = findViewById<TextView> 
(R.id.[textview Id from you Xml 
layout])
val countString = 
textView.text.toString()
```

Comment: textView is the View ID of the text field in the layout of the activity. In this context, textView is the identifier for the text field in the activity_main.xml file, which is used to lay out the user interface.